# Display underscore as space in Label

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

In my app I have a tableview with a dynamic list of cells of the Basic style. The textLabel for each cell is pulled from xml and contains underscores in place of spaces.  I use the label text to identify which cell is tapped in didSelectRowAtIndexPath and match it to other occurrences of the same string in other xml files.  For this to work the label needs to contain the underscores, however it would look nicer if they were spaces instead.

So my question is, can I set the labelText to display the underscores as spaces but preserve the underscores in the underlying string so it still matches the xml where underscores are used?

Comment: I would rethink the architecture of your table view controller. You shouldn't tightly couple the way it is displayed with its representation in the model. You need to allow for the view (the table view and cells in this case) to be able to transform your data objects into a representation that makes sense to the user, irregardless of the underlying representation. Is there any way you could do it by tracking the indexes of data? i.e. is your data in a sorted array that you could look up the original value from an index path when the cell is tapped?

Comment: I am storing my data in a MutableArray as it is read by NSXMLParser.  So I believe I could access the data using the array index by storing the index in the tag for the matching cell.  I understand that using a cell in a table to pass data to the next view is poor design.  Thanks for the advice @CarlVeazey

Comment: you're very welcome, let me know if I can help you out at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the labelText display anything you like. In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` just configure the cell with a string that you've substituted spaces for underscores (see `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` to do that easily).

Comment: Thanks, I will give stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString a go.

Answer (score 1):

You could have an array of strings as pulled from the XML and then filter the underscores into spaces when you put the label into the display cell. That's probably how I'd approach it. Or for that matter, you can filter the string both directions, but it's probably more straightforward to just store the version from the XML file, my opinion anyhow.

Comment: I had considered this option but using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString to alter the string when required seems to me to be a more elegant solution.  Maintaining a array as you suggested is a good fallback option if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, I don't think the current design is optimal for the requirements, but if there's absolutely no other way to do it than by essentially storing the data in the cell's label, I'd do it like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)ip
{
    /* instantiate cell here */
    NSString *cellText = /* however you need to get the cell text */;
    cellText = [cellText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@" "];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellText;
    /* whatever other cell setup you need */
}
```

Then in the selection callback:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)ip
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip];
    NSString *cellText = cell.textLabel.text;
    cellText = [cellText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_"];
    /* go do whatever with cellText */
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new string replacing the _ with a space. This will keep your original string unmodified (which typically isn't an issue as it is probably Immutable (i.e. NSString not NSMutableString)).

```
self.labelText.text = [incomingString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@" "];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subclass of NSValueTransformer which just replaces occurrences of '_' with ' ' this wont affect the value, but would change the appearance if the button's stringValue was bound to the value, with a value transformer option.

This assumes the button's stringValue is set via bindings, the other answers assume the text is set manually.

Comment: Are binding available on iOS?